# How to put an image behind a text box?

Tags: css

I have [this linked code](http://jsfiddle.net/q2rpp/), which creates a transparent text box with an overlapped image. However, how do I get the image to be behind the text box, with the transparency effect? Right now, the image is blocking the text etc.

Thanks.

```
    <div class="grid12-6">
<!-- start text box div -->
<div style="z-index:1;width: 75%; -webkit-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; background:rgba(0,120,0,0.5); padding: 25px 0px 25px 25px; -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px;">
<ul style="font-size: larger;color:#fff;">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end text box div -->
    <div style="z-index:0;position: relative;top:-25px">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the textbox in your code??

Comment: use `background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200)` on your text box.

Comment: everything within the <!-- start text box div --><!-- end text box div --> is for me the 'text box'. As you can see in the fiddle link. Cheers.

Comment: thanks, any chance of a fiddle edit to help on that? I can only get the image wrapping  in the box :( http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2bETy/

Comment: Both containers should have position attribute. Btw, the code in your jsfiddle is completely different from your question.

Comment: OH GOD!! sorry!!! I updated the link now to http://jsfiddle.net/q2rpp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just add the `position: relative;` onto your text box div.

Remember, the `z-index` could just be useful between elements with `position: relative | absolute | fixed`.

```
<div class="grid12-6">
<!-- start text box div -->
<div style="position: relative; z-index:1;width: 75%; -webkit-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; background:rgba(0,120,0,0.5); padding: 25px 0px 25px 25px; -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px;">
<ul style="font-size: larger;color:#fff;">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end text box div -->
    <div style="z-index:0;position: relative;top:-25px">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

It worked. [Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/edisonator/2bETy/322/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .inputBox{
          background-image:url('bg.png');
          background-repeat:repeat-y;
          padding-left:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <ul style="font-size: larger;color:#fff;">
                <li>some text</li>
                <li>some text</li>
                <li>some text</li>
                <li>some text</li>
                <li>some text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks - the fix from Edisonator seemed to do the job for me (and sorry about error in example at the start)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bETy/324/)

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2bETy/325/)

```
<div class="img_destination">

      <img src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/gsm/images/featured_destination/gcfv.png" alt="" />

    <h2 id="featured_destination"><span class="bold">>> Explore Fuerteventura</span><span class='spacer'></span><span class='spacer'></span>The island of natural beauty</h2>

</div><div class="grid12-6">
<!-- start text box div -->
<div style="z-index:1;width: 75%; -webkit-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; background:rgba(0,120,0,0.5); padding: 25px 0px 25px 25px; -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px;">
<ul style="font-size: larger;color:#fff;">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end text box div -->
    <div style="z-index:0;position: relative;top:-25px">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" style="height: 100px;margin-top: 15%;" /></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED QUERY:**

```
 <div style="z-index:1;width: 75%; -webkit-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;margin-top: 20px;; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; background:rgba(0,120,0,0.5); padding: 25px 0px 25px 25px; -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px;">
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks - the fix from Edisonator seemed to do the job for me (and sorry about error in example at the start)

Answer (score 0):

You could add background-image to the div style:

```
<div class="grid12-6">
<!-- start text box div -->
<div style="z-index:1;width: 75%; -webkit-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px; background:rgba(0,120,0,0.5); padding: 25px 0px 25px 25px; -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; box-shadow: #B3B3B3 5px 5px 5px; 
background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<ul style="font-size: larger;color:#fff;">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```